# Disabling node editing after first node flagging

Tags: rules, flags

I use flagging for signing petitions. Petitions should be editable until the first signing (flagging) is done.

Now I look for a solution to disable node edition after first signing.

My first thought is doing it with Rules. I have access to flagging reactions, node type conditions but I have no action for editability of nodes.

Is there another way to get it done with Rules or something without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D7, no need of rules, place this code in your MODULE

```
function MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
 if ($op == 'update') {
  $flag='';
  $flag = flag_get_flag('YOUR_FLAG_MACHINE_NAME');
            if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($node->nid, $GLOBALS['user']->uid)) {
  return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }
}
```

done, enyoy.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But it's about a D8. Sorry, my mistake.